# Video acceleration disabled in Mint Linux 15 (Olivia) on an Intel Atom processor

Tags: linux-mint, intel, gpu, atom

Recently I installed Mint Linux 15 (Olivia) 32 bit on my friends netbook. I am copy pasting the output of *sudo lspci -vk*

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx DRAM Controller (rev 03)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 061f
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 061f
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
Memory at 86000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
I/O ports at 50d0 [size=8]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=07 <?>
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Kernel driver in use: gma500
```

So the problem is whenever I try to boot into the system it pops out a notification (not the exact words)

```
Running in software rendering mode. No Hardware acceleration.
```

I have searched the Mint Linux forum and found [this thread] (http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=135578&p=727654), but it did not help much. I am also attaching the output of *inxi -Fxz*

```
Kernel: 3.8.0-19-generic i686 (32 bit, gcc: 4.7.3)
Desktop: Gnome
Distro: Linux Mint 15 Olivia
Machine:   
System: Acer product: AOD270 version: V1.06
Mobo: Acer model: JE01_CT
Bios: Insyde version: V1.06 date: 03/05/2012
CPU:
Dual core Intel Atom CPU N2600 (-HT-MCP-)
cache: 512 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 ssse3) bmips: 6383.8
Clock Speeds: 1: 1600.00 MHz 2: 1600.00 MHz 3: 1600.00 MHz 4: 1600.00 MHz

Graphics:
Card: Intel Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx
Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
X.Org: 1.13.3 drivers: vesa (unloaded: fbdev)
Resolution: 1024x600@60.0hz
GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.2, 128 bits)
GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 9.1.1
Direct Rendering: Yes
```

The direct effect of disabled hardware video acceleration is that it is impossible to play video files and since the CPU is engaged with software acceleration, the system is damn too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fellow owner of a Dell 3000 / Intel-865G provided me with the following solution.

Create / edit / save this file ('vi', notepad, et al), 
`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-xorg.conf` that contains the following content:

```
Section "Screen"
     Identifier "Default Screen"
     DefaultDepth 24
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only get these to work with `32bit`, `Ubuntu 12.04`-based systems. I recently reinstalled on of these, and I got the hardware video acceleration to work with `Linux Mint 13` (not the newer ones).

Couple of years ago when I got that netbook, I had to compile a patched kernel to get the video acceleration to work. Later, the drivers became available as prepackaged loadable kernel modules, so now you just need to install the packages with `cedarview` in the name of the package.